# Color in triangle position

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get the color of the part of two images that are inside a triangle and make another triangle in the same position with the average of them. The following code draws a triangle in the images:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv){


  Scalar color(0,0,255);
  Point2f p0(50,50),p1(100,50), p2(50,100);

  Mat img1 = imread("img1.png");
  Mat img2 = imread("img2.png");
  Mat triangle(img1.rows,img1.cols,img1.type());
  triangle.setTo(color);

  line(img1, p0, p1, color, 1, CV_AA, 0);
  line(img1, p1, p2, color, 1, CV_AA, 0);
  line(img1, p2, p0, color, 1, CV_AA, 0);

  line(img2, p0, p1, color, 1, CV_AA, 0);
  line(img2, p1, p2, color, 1, CV_AA, 0);
  line(img2, p2, p0, color, 1, CV_AA, 0);

   // if contain triangle get the color of two images
   // triangle[i][j] = (img1[i][j] + img2[i][j])/2 ;



  imwrite("out1.png",img1);
  imwrite("out2.png",img2);
 // imwrite( "triangle.png",triangle);

  return 0;
}
```

I want to get the color of each pixel contained in the triangle that can be anywhere in the image.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you going to show us the image and mark on it what you are looking for?

Comment: The images do not matter. Given two images I want to get the content (color of each pixel) of the triangle that can be in any position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to think of image processing as mathematics rather than images... so if you just average your 2 input images you will get the average colour at all locations. Then, if you only want the answer inside a triangle, make it so the triangle has pixel values of `1` inside the triangle and `0` everywhere else. Then multiply the averaged image by the triangle image and it will go black outside the triangle (from being multiplied by zero), and just be the average inside the triangle (from being multiplied by one).

So, just in uncompiled/untested pseudo code:

```
// Load two images
Mat img1 = imread("img1.png");
Mat img2 = imread("img2.png");

// Make black mask image
Scalar black(0,0,0);
Mat mask(img1.rows,img1.cols,img1.type());
mask.setTo(black);

// Draw triangle filled with value "1" in mask 
Point vertices[1][3];
vertices[0][0] = Point( 50, 50  );
vertices[0][1] = Point( 100, 50 );
vertices[0][2] = Point( 50, 100 );

const Point* ppt[1] = { vertices[0] };
int npt[] = { 3 };
fillPoly( mask, ppt, npt, 1, Scalar( 1, 1, 1 ), 8 );

Mat result;
result = mask * (img1 + img2) / 2;
```